# Гарантировать отсутствие null после match

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, code-style, статический-анализ, eslint

Может ли статический анализатор javascript-кода проверить, что регулярное выражение будет давать совпадение на любой строке?

```
s.match(/\w*/)[0]           // valid
s.match(/\w+/)[0]           // invalid
s.match(/id(\d{7})/)[1]     // invalid
s.match(/id(\d{7})|$/)[1]   // valid
```

Есть может, то есть ли уже такой плагин для какого-либо анализатора?

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/50687816/4928642)

Answer (score 2):

Если регулярное выражение дает совпадение с **позицией**, **началом текста** и **концом текста**, то оно **valid**, потому что эти три возможных варианта совпадений присутствуют в любом тексте.
Позиция это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во всех остальных случаях всегда можно найти текст, который не даст совпадений на регулярном выражении.

Анализ регулярного выражения следует проводить следующим образом: сначала надо проверить совпадет ли регулярное выражение с пустой строкой. Если не совпадет, то оно **invalid**, если совпадет, то необходимо построить AST регулярного выражения, выделить всё, что описывает литералы и найти такой литерал, который НЕ указан в регулярном выражении.
То есть для `[^abc]` таким литералом будет `a`, `b` и `c`. Для `[a-z]` таким литералом будет любой литерал не входящий в этот диапазон.
Если такой литерал найти не удалось, то мы не смогли решить задачу и я бы предложил бросить попытки анализа и считать регулярное выражение **invalid**.
Если такой литерал найти удалось, то применяем регулярное выражение к тексту, состоящему из минимум двух таких литералов.
Если совпадение есть, то регулярное выражение **valid**, если нет, то **invalid**.

Comment: 1. Почему если ему удовлетворяет символ, не входящий в выражение, ему будет удовлетворять что угодно? 2. Я бы предположил, что стоит добавлять какие-то маркеры в AST, чтобы понять ответ. 3. Про 256! какая-то ерунда. Длина строки не ограничена, символы могут повторяться, а у тебя число всех перестановок.

Comment: Это были наброски идеи, первое что пришло в голову. Перед тем как уснул подумал над задачей и нашёл алгоритм-решение.

Comment: А блин. Грусть печаль :-( Вы просто плагин искали, а я в теорию подался :-( Сомневаюсь, что такой плагин существует, но Вы можете его написать :-)

Comment: Теорию - тоже интересно.

Comment: 1. _`(?=a*)(b?|c+)` => `0+0*1`_ - это не понял. 2. `(?!a)` - как считается? 3. Предпросмотр как считается? 4. Обратные ссылки как считаются? 5. Про позиции либо странно, либо непонятно.

Comment: Позиционные просмотры как сложение раскрываются. Возможно, что для каких-то конструкций позиционные просмотры будут раскрываться как умножение. Обратные ссылки будут иметь то же значение, что и соответствующая группа. Я не обладаю знаниями, чтобы дать исчерпывающий ответ- необходимые знания можно получить путём исследования. Надеюсь, что Вы поймете сам принцип, который я описал.

Comment: `(?!...)` скорее всего всегда раскрывается как 0.

Comment: Хотя как раскрыть невозможные шаблоны- совсем не понятно. Например `(?=$.)` по моей теории это должно стать единицей. Так что подход из первой версии ответа легче реализовать корректно :-)

Comment: @ReinRaus, а для случая `^\w*$`?

Comment: @Grundy 0+0+0, позиции - это 0, если они не требуют обязательно символ и 1, если символ требуется.

Comment: @ReinRaus, что-то я так и не понял. Если 0+0+0 - тогда получается для любой строки подходит, но оно ж не для любой, а только для пустой, либо с буквами.

Comment: да, верно. Тупая теория. Верну первую версию ответа.

Comment: @ReinRaus, да мог бы оставить, просто критерий применимости какой-нибудь добавить. Идея то интересная